# How many ways can I make "Hello Wolrd" output?

Tags: javascript

To make "Hello World" output, what is `var a`? How many ways do you know?

```js
var a = ???;
if(a==1 && a ==10) {
  console.log("Hello World");
  // Hello World
}
```

Comment: Seems like a joke :)

Comment: Please research well before asking. your question has obvious answers in the web.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways.  You can write "Hello World" to a file, read it back in and print it.  You can read it back in, write it to another file, read that file back in and print it.  It's turtles all the way down. 

Comment: Here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/fb9jgm53/

Comment: Love it @TiiJ7 heheheh

Comment: Thank you for your advice and I had got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS for the win! The [Object.prototype.valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) did the trick for me.

```js
var a = {
  count: 0,
  valueOf: function(){ 
    if(this.count === 0) {
      this.count++;
      return 1;
    } else { 
      return 10 
    } 
  }
};

if(a==1 && a ==10) {
  console.log("Hello World");
  // Hello World
}
```